# Variant of ridge regression loss function

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

We can create variants of the loss function, especially of ridge regression by adding more regularizer terms.  One of the variants I saw in a book is given below

$min_{w \in \mathbf{R}^d} \  \  \alpha.||w||^2 + (1-\alpha).||w||^4 + C||y-X^T.w||^2$

where $y \in \mathbf{R^n}, s \in \mathbf{R^d}, X \in \mathbf{R^{dxn}}$ and $C$ a regularization parameter $\in \mathbf{R}$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$

My question is how does change in $\alpha$ affects our optimization problem? and how does generally adding more regularizers help? why is not one regularizer enough?